# how to get matching key using the value in a map C++

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, struct

I have a map with a struct as a value type

```
map<int id, struct_t*> table

struct_t
{
int prev;
int wt;
string name;
}
```

Using only prev, I need to find the corresponding id. Thanks so much in advance!

EDIT:

```
int key=0;
for(auto it = table.begin(); it != table.end(); ++it)
{
     if(table[(*it).first].prev == ?)
}
```

This is how my map data looks like:

```
id    prev abundance  thing
1573  -1      0       book
1864  1573    39      beds
2075  1864    41      tray
1760  2075    46      cups
```

For each id, I need to find the NEXT matching id. So, for 1573 from the prev column I need to find a matching 'id' which is 1864. Also, std::next doesn't work because the data set can have the matching ids not necessarily in the next element.Hope this helps!

PLEASE PLEASE help me!!! MY boss is already disappointed that I'm taking so much time to learn C++ (its been 3 weeks already!)

Comment: What is the key of the `map`?

Comment: do you mean the data type? it is int id

Comment: Maps are meant to be searched on their keys, not values. Maybe you should tweak your design or use another kind of container.

Comment: It takes more than 3 weeks to become proficient at C++...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you've got a modern compiler (supports lambdas), you can do the following:

```
const int prevToFind = 10;
auto findResult = std::find_if(std::begin(table), std::end(table), [&](const std::pair<int, struct_t*> &pair)
{
    return pair.second->prev == prevToFind;
});

int foundKey = 0; // You might want to initialise this to a value you know is invalid in your map
struct_t *foundValue = nullptr
if (findResult != std::end(table))
{
    foundKey = findResult->first;
    foundValue = findResult->second;

    // Now do something with the key or value!
}
```

Let me know if you have an older compiler, and I can update the example to use a predicate class instead.

Comment: I don't really understand this..I don't need the struct, I need the key which is an int.

Comment: You want the key? It sounds like your map is backwards... It's an easy change to the above code (just use findResult->first).

Comment: It worked!!thank you soooooo much!! If I knew your address, I'd send you chocolates!

Comment: Haha that's ok, just click the tick next to my answer to mark it as the right answer. :-)

Comment: Wonderful wonderful solution with std::find_if and lamda :-).

Answer (score 8):

Simple loop can do it:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   std::map<int, std::string> m = {
      std::make_pair(0, "zero"), std::make_pair(1, "one"), std::make_pair(2, "two")
   };

   int key = 0;
   for (auto &i : m) {
      if (i.second == "two") {
         key = i.first;
         break; // to stop searching
      }
   }

   std::cout << key << std::endl;
}
```

Of course you need to set up your own if-statement for searching.
Please note, boost bidirectional map could be a solution ([boost::bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html))

Comment: So, I added the direction in which I'm headed, but I don't know what I should be comparing in the if statement!

Comment: try `if (i.second->prev == the_id_youre_looking_for)`

Comment: This looks a lot simpler to me than the accepted answer. I don't understand why this did not have any up-votes...

Answer (score 6):

Looping over the map of course does the trick, but you may want to consider using a second map as an index:

```
map<int,int> table_idx;
```

Whenever you add new entries to `table` you will need to update `table_idx` as well, storing  the `id` that corresponds to every `prev`. `table_idx` will then allow you to reverse-lookup the `id` in log(N) time:

```
int prev_for_id = table_idx[id];
```

Comment: what do you mean by looping over the map?

Comment: I was referring to the approach adopted in some of the answers above: iterating over each entry in the map until you find the value whose `prev` field equals the `id` you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Im getting a feeling that you are a beginner so it would be nice if you would tell us what are you trying to do because maybe you are trying to solve a wrong problem.
 Like noted maps are designed to be searched by the key, not value.
 That being said if you insist on searching the map this way you will problably wanna check out **Boost Bimap**.

Comment: Yes, I am a beginner. I've been struggling with this project for 3 weeks now! I'll update the question

Comment: ok, I think understand your problem. Of the top of my head I would first put all data in a map(with added field next that is initially unitialized). Then I would go through entire map and for each key that has value.prev==Y do map[Y]->value.next=X

Comment: Im kind of in a rush so i have no time to test it, but you might wanna try it out for yourself and fix bugs if you can...#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct mystruct
{
int prev;
int next;
int wt;
string name;
};

std::map<int , mystruct> table;
int main()
{
  mystruct first;
  mystruct second;
  table[11] = first;
  table[22] = second;
  for (auto& el: table)
  {
     if (el.second.prev!=-1)
 table[el.second.prev].next=el.first;
  }
  
}

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to generate a reverse **map** with something like that:

```
typedef std::map<int, struct_t*> map_t;
typedef std::map<struct_t*, int> reverse_map_t;

reverse_map_t get_reverse( map_t m )
{
    reverse_map_t r;
    for( const auto& p: m )
    {
        r[p.second] = p.first;
    }
    return r;
}
```